# How to know if your decision tree model has overfitting or not?

Tags: scikit-learn, accuracy, multi-class

I am using the DecisionTreeClassifier() of python and I am changing some tuning parameters to understand if my model has overfitting or no because when I exectue the following code without any modification on the tunining parameters:

```
clf=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf=clf.fit(train_data, train_target)
```

I got :

```
scores_train = cross_val_score(clf, train_data, train_target, cv=5)
```

it gives me

```
array([ 0.96851574,  0.97149287,  0.96924231,  0.96621622,  0.96919609])
```

but when I excute

```
accuracy_score(train_target, predict_trainLabel)
```

It gives me 1.0 
while for the testing accuracy I got the following results :

```
scores_test=cross_val_score(clf, test_data, test_target, cv=5)
scores_test
Out[69]: array([ 0.97376312,  0.97074269,  0.97297297,  0.97672673,  0.97520661])
```

and the follwoing instruction gave me this

```
test_accuracy =accuracy_score(test_target, predict_testLabel)
test_accuracy
Out[72]: 0.97568297808465931
```

I did not understand the relation between validation accuracy and training accuracy obtained by accuracy_score to juge my model ? does my model has any overfitting?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Try comparing in-sample fit to test-set/cross-validated predictions.

Comment: @Jim Hi! thank you but I am new in machine learning and I did not understand it what means in sample?

Comment: in-sample here means your training error.

Comment: training accuracy is 1.0 means my training error is 0 while the testing accuracy 0.98 means my testing error is 0.18